# How to add async to resource file while using @Styles.Render in ASP.NET bundling?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-bundling

Although I am working in Sitecore application but had implemented [ASP.NET bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for minification of some of the resource files.

My question is can we add async property to a bundled file rendered using `@Styles.Render` method?

In layout this has been `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")` added and below is the bundle table registration:

[image]

**Output**

[image]

What I need is:

```
<link href="/bundles/css?v=qJHzaYh2DdlW6ioB10YzF1YhQUJqGncz6xM6vUV2sAA1" rel="stylesheet" async/>
```

Note: I have already tried using `@Styles.Url` to get the bundled url and adding to the link and marking it async but due to some reasons its not working in given env.

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching, i found pretty straight forward solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Styles.Url("~/bundles/css")" async>
```

Output:
[image]